# MediaPlayer in BroadcastReceiver not working in Android

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

I have an issue getting MediaPlayer in a BroadcastReceiver to work. What I want to do in high level, is to play a sound and a vibration x minutes after a notification from Firebase comes, like a second reminder.
I have a class that extends *FirebaseMessagingService* and in the *onMessageReceived()* method I call the *setOnetimeTimer(this)* which is:

```
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 1), pi); // 1 minute
}
```

Then the *AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver()* is:

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.my_weird_sound);
    mp.start();
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(1000);

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The vibration is executed without a problem but the sound is not playing and the error that I am getting is:

```
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
```

keep in mind also that I have *AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver* in my manifest.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These type of exception arise when MediaPlayer has not implemented its architecture properly. [Achitecure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Now try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp=null;
        }
        else {
            mp = null;
        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.my_weird_sound);
        mp.start();
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(1000);

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.release();
                }
                else {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The messages on the logcat stayed the same but now it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Comment: **D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer** this warning occurs when you dont add Subtitle to MediaPlayer, you can ignore this warning.